# Input Value showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm fairly new to javascript and trying to make a simple To Do list work. I have the basic functionality down, but I'm trying to understand why the input value in my code is returning undefined?

The remove button adds just fine, so I know the function is working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <title>To Do List</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="content__container">
          <div class="list__container">
            <div class="header__container">
              <h1 class="header__title">TO DO LIST</h1>
              <input id="header__input" type="text" />
              <button class="header__button">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="list__content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".header__button");
const listContent = document.querySelector(".list__content");
let input = document.getElementById("header__input").value;

function addItem() {
  const toDoItem = document.createElement("li");
  const text = document.createTextNode(input);
  const remove = document.createElement("button");

  remove.textContent = "remove";
  remove.classList.add("list__remove");
  toDoItem.classList.add("list__items");

  toDoItem.appendChild(text);
  toDoItem.appendChild(remove);
  listContent.appendChild(toDoItem);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addItem);
```

Comment: Change `let input = document.getElementById("header__input").value;` and `const text = document.createTextNode(input);` to `let input = document.getElementById("header__input");` and `const text = document.createTextNode(input.value);`. At the point you're getting the value the input element is empty - you need to access the value _after_ the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is getting the input value only when it start and not when the function is called.

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".header__button");

function addItem() {
    const listContent = document.querySelector(".list__content");
    let input = document.getElementById("header__input").value;

    const toDoItem = document.createElement("li");
    const text = document.createTextNode(input);
    const remove = document.createElement("button");

    remove.textContent = "remove";
    remove.classList.add("list__remove");
    toDoItem.classList.add("list__items");

    toDoItem.appendChild(text);
    toDoItem.appendChild(remove);
    listContent.appendChild(toDoItem);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addItem);
```

Moving **listContent** and the **input variable** into the function will ensure that you get the values ​​every time the function is executed.